# Verifying an enumerable list in Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method which looks like this:

```
public int Save(IEnumerable<int> addedIds, IEnumerable<int> removedIds)
{
    var existingIds = repository.Get();
    IEnumerable<int> ids = existingIds.Except(removedIds).Union(addedIds));
    return repository.Create(ids);
}
```

The test in Moq looks like this:

```
repository.Setup(r => r.Get()).Returns(CreateList());
service.Save(addedIds, removedIds);
repository.Verify(r => r.Create(It.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(l => VerifyList(l))));
```

This fails, with this error<s>, and `VerifyList()` is never called:</s>

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never
>   performed:
>
> `r => r.Create(It.Is<IEnumerable'1>(list => VerifyList(list)))`
>
> Performed invocations:
>
> `IRepo.Create(System.Linq.Enumerable+<UnionIterator>d__88'1[System.Int32])`

As the invoked type is not `IEnumerable<int>` but is in fact `System.Linq.Enumerable+<UnionIterator>d__88'1[System.Int32])`, the test fails. (Stepping through the test, everything is happening correctly and the results are as expected)

If I call `ids.ToList()` in the method under test, these are the results:

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed:
>
> `r => r.Create(It.Is<List'1>(l => VerifyList(l)))`
>
> Performed invocations:
>   `IRepo.Create(System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32])`

Is there any way round this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: it turns out I had a mistake in my VerifyList method so it was returning false, but Moq wasn't giving me that information. The type difference is a red herring..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work. Made some assumptions though. Guess the VerifyList method could be better. =)

```
[Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        // SETUP
        Mock<IRepository> repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
        Service service = new Service(repository.Object);
        repository.Setup(r => r.Get()).Returns(CreateList());

        IEnumerable<int> addedIds = new[]{1,2};
        IEnumerable<int> removedIds = new[]{3,4};
        service.Save(addedIds, removedIds);

        repository.Verify(r => r.Create(It.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(l => VerifyList(l))));
    }

    private static bool VerifyList(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.Contains(1) && enumerable.Contains(2) && enumerable.Contains(5);
    }

    private IEnumerable<int> CreateList()
    {
        return new[] { 3, 4, 5 };
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<int> Get();
        int Create(IEnumerable<int> id);
    }
    public class Service
    {
        public Service(IRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
        }

        private IRepository repository;

        public int Save(IEnumerable<int> addedIds, IEnumerable<int> removedIds)
    {
        var existingIds = repository.Get();
            IEnumerable<int> ids = existingIds.Except(removedIds).Union(addedIds);

        return repository.Create(ids);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that test does pass with my version of Moq. I still don't understand why mine fails..

Comment: That's odd. Could you update Moq? Which version of Moq are you using?

Comment: I had an error in my VerifyList method, which it turns out was being called after all. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
var another = new List<int> { 1 , 2, 3 };
repository.Verify(r => r.Create(It.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(l => l.SequenceEqual(another)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Something quick and dirty -

```
public interface IBlah
{
    void Sum(IEnumerable<int> baz);
}

class Blah : IBlah
{
    public void Sum(IEnumerable<int> baz)
    {
        return;
    }
}

public class Baz
{
    private readonly IBlah blah;

    public Baz(IBlah blah)
    {
        this.blah = blah;
    }

    public void Sum(IEnumerable<int> baz)
    {
        blah.Sum(baz);
    }
}
```

And Test it like -

```
[Test]
public void foo()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IBlah>();
    var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

    var baz = new Baz(mock.Object);
    baz.Sum(enumerable.Where(x => x%2 == 0));

    mock.Verify(p => p.Sum(It.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(z => z.All(x => x%2==0))));
}
```